# scipy.stats doesn't work right with frozen RV

Tags: python, scipy

I am using scipy.stats.  Most distributions allow you to "freeze" an RV like so:

```
rv=scipy.stats.norm(mean, sigma)
```

then, later, you can ask for (say):

```
 rv.pdf(0)
```

or

```
rv.mean()
```

and get a value that makes sense (in this case 0.5 and 0, respectively).

The t-dist offers a 'loc' and 'scale' param, but they don't seem to freeze.  In other words, by testing, you can set

```
rv = scipy.stats.t(df=100000, loc=5, scale=2),
```

and a graph looks like a normal dist (given the huge DOF) centered at 5 w/ stdev=2.

However, when you as for mean() or stdev() , it gives you (consistent with the documentation) the results for a normalized t-dist, with loc = 0 and stdev = 1.

Any ideas? This seems a break with the rest of scipy.stats.

Comment: *"However, when you as for mean() or stdev() , it gives you (consistent with the documentation) the results for a normalized t-dist, with loc = 0 and stdev = 1."*  I can't reproduce this.  It would be easier to help you if you included a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that someone can copy and run without editing to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct me if I understood the problem wrong, but when I run this code

```
import scipy
import scipy.stats
from scipy.stats import t

rv_t = t(df=100000, loc=12, scale=2)
print(rv_t.mean())
```

I see the mean of the t-dist as 12(Namely the equivalent of loc value)

Comment: Not sure why, but for some reason it was not doing that yesterday.  Might be tied to the Python version?